# How can I make file I/O more transactional?

Tags: haskell, io

I'm writing CGI scripts in Haskell. When the user hits ‘submit’, a Haskell program runs on the server, updating (i.e. reading in, processing, overwriting) a status file. Reading then overwriting sometimes causes issues with lazy IO, as we may be able to generate a large output prefix before we've finished reading the input. Worse, users sometimes bounce on the submit button and two instances of the process run concurrently, fighting over the same file!

What's a good way to implement

```
transactionalUpdate :: FilePath -> (String -> String) -> IO ()
```

where the function (‘update’) computes the new file contents from the old file contents? It is not safe to presume that ‘update’ is strict, but it may be presumed that it is total (robustness to partial update functions is a bonus). Transactions may be attempted concurrently, but no transaction should be able to update if the file has been written by anyone else since it was read. It's ok for a transaction to abort in case of competition for file access. We may assume a source of systemwide-unique temporary filenames.

My current attempt writes to a temporary file, then uses a system copy command to overwrite. That seems to deal with the lazy IO problems, but it doesn't strike me as safe from races. Is there a tried and tested formula that we could just bottle?

Comment: A temporary file followed by a rename is the usual way.  It works pretty well on most platforms.

Comment: I think that's the basis of it, but I might need locking too. Otherwise I get A-reads B-reads A-writes B-writes. I wonder if I can make creative use of write-locks to avoid that.

Comment: @pigworker, what if you rename the file before reading? I think renaming should be atomic on the file-system level.

Comment: @Rotsor That might indeed be a good way to take a lock. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most idiomatic unixy way to do this is with flock:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/flock
- http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/2/flock

Comment: Ooh, has someone bottled it already? Looks like that handles the locking, leaving me just the tail-chasing-avoidance problem. That said, using this locking mechanism militates against a renaming-based approach to the latter.

Comment: I think the renaming approach to the latter is fine. Flocks are advisory opt-in locks. Grab a lock on a "file.ext". Then write to "file.ext.out" then rename over "file.ext" and finally release the lock?

Comment: Yes, as long as I ensure that there's no competition for the temporary filename while I have the lock on the main file, it should be ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rough first cut that relies on the atomicity of the underlying `mkdir`. It seems to fulfill the specification, but I'm not sure how robust or fast it is:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception
import System.Directory
import System.IO

transactionalUpdate :: FilePath -> (String -> String) -> IO ()
transactionalUpdate file upd = bracket acquire release update
  where
    acquire = do
      let lockName = file ++ ".lock"
      createDirectory lockName
      return lockName
    release = removeDirectory
    update _ = nonTransactionalUpdate file upd

nonTransactionalUpdate :: FilePath -> (String -> String) -> IO ()
nonTransactionalUpdate file upd = do
  h <- openFile file ReadMode
  s <- upd `fmap` hGetContents h
  s `deepseq` hClose h
  h <- openFile file WriteMode
  hPutStr h s
  hClose h
```

I tested this by adding the following `main` and throwing a `threadDelay` in the middle of `nonTransactionalUpdate`:

```
main = do
  [n] <- getArgs
  transactionalUpdate "foo.txt" ((show n ++ "\n") ++)
  putStrLn $ "successfully updated " ++ show n
```

Then I compiled and ran a bunch of instances with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                     

rm foo.txt
touch foo.txt
for i in {1..50}
do
    ./SO $i &
done
```

A process that printed a successful update message if and only if the corresponding number was in `foo.txt`; all the others printed the expected `SO: foo.txt.notveryunique: createDirectory: already exists (File exists)`.

**Update:** You actually do *not* want to use unique names here; it must be a consistent name across the competing processes. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: After seeing @Rotsor's comment on the original question, I think renaming the original file would work as well; either way, you're getting down to the level where system calls should guarantee atomicity.

Comment: At the moment I'm thinking it's rename file to file-in, process file-in to file-out (lazily, no worries!), rename file-out to file. Any way up, it's a good steer to use atomic file system operations for the taking and release of locks. Thanks also for the steer about testing, too.

Comment: No worries; I agree it's a simpler solution, and more robust against things like my original error of suggesting a unique suffix. You should be able to drop it into the `acquire` and `release` definitions I wrote above.

Comment: It sounds like flocks are the way to go, but thanks for all your help.